# Spam emails for download?

Tags: spam

Is there a place where I could download as much spam emails as possible, having been sent from as much different worldwide locations as possible?

To clarify: I am *not* after databases which contain hashes of spam emails or which contain IP addresses of senders / networks which have sent spam. I am just interested in getting hold of as much real spam emails as possible in unaltered form.

For example, this could be a giant mbox file containing thousands or millions of such emails in their original state. Are there some anti-spam organizations or companies who provide access to such data?

**UPDATE:**

Not being a native English speaker, I just didn't know the right keywords. Just search for "spam corpus" or "spam corpora" on Google. Hoping that this helps others with the same problem and hoping that now there's no reason to downvote any more ...

Comment: I kindly ask to explain why the question is inappropriate ... I'd really like to learn.

Comment: In a small ISP I know they got around 6TB of spam per week that they filter. Want to kill your WAN's link ?

Comment: Just assign a domain to your IP, open port 25 & enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) maintained a download of SPAM/HAM called a corpus.  But you really want to use your own emails to train.  Otherwise you'll be training your filters with antiquated email.

UPDATE: It appears that SpamAssassin is now using submitted corpora.  But there are plenty of public ones:

- http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~gvcormac/treccorpus/
- http://www.cc.gatech.edu/projects/doi/WebbSpamCorpus.html

Comment: I eventually have a new unconventional idea concerning spam fighting (which isn't based on some sort of training). To test the idea, I need as much test data as possible. It won't matter how old the data is (well, probably it shouldn't be older than a few years).